# Problems plotting a 2D random walk with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm trying to create a 2D random walk with Python. The random walk is to occur within a square, and if the particle crosses any side of the square the particle is to appear on the other side -- in effect, the random walk is occurring on a torus.

Here's a copy of my code:

```
from random import randrange as rand
from math import cos, sin, radians
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 100   # Size of square as a multiple of the step size.
NSteps = 5000   # Number of steps in simulation.
xStart = 0   # x coordinate of starting location. Origin is at centre of square
yStart = 0   # y coordinate of starting location. Origin is at centre of square

s = 1   # Step number.
x = xStart   # x coordinate of point.
y = yStart   # y coordinate of point.
xList = []   # List of the x coordinates of all points visited.
yList = []   # List of the y coordinates of all points visited.

while s <= NSteps:
    angle = radians(rand(361))
    x += cos(angle)    
    if x > N/2:
        x -= N
    elif x < -N/2:
        x += N    
    xList += [x]
    y += sin(angle)
    if y > N/2:
        y -= N
    elif y < -N/2:
        y += N
    yList += [y]    
    s += 1

plt.figure(figsize=(13,8))
frame = plt.gca()
plt.plot(xList,yList,c="b")
plt.xlim(-N/2,N/2)
plt.ylim(-N/2,N/2)
frame.axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
frame.axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
plt.savefig("randomWalk.png", bbox_inches="tight")
```

This code produces a plot like this:
[image]

As you can see, whenever the particle crosses one of the sides I get these 'streaks' on the plot because `plot()` will connect two points no matter how far apart they are. Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

Comment: I would guess you'll probably have to do it manually (e.g. split up contiguous pieces of the walk and plot them separately) - the plotting code has no way of knowing where the discontinuities are.

Comment: You can also throw a `np.nan` into both the series where you do the wrap around code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also re-wrote your steping code a bit to make it easier (in my opinion) to read:

```
from random import randrange as rand
from numpy import cos, sin, radians
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 100   # Size of square as a multiple of the step size.
NSteps = 5000   # Number of steps in simulation.
xStart = 0   # x coordinate of starting location. Origin is at centre of square
yStart = 0   # y coordinate of starting location. Origin is at centre of square

s = 1   # Step number.
x = xStart   # x coordinate of point.
y = yStart   # y coordinate of point.
xList = []   # List of the x coordinates of all points visited.
yList = []   # List of the y coordinates of all points visited.

def wrap(v, N):

    if v > N/2:
        return v - N, True
    elif v < -N/2:
        return v + N, True
    return v, False


for j in range(NSteps):
    angle = radians(rand(361))
    x, wrap_flag_x = wrap(x + cos(angle), N)
    y, wrap_flag_y = wrap(y + sin(angle), N)
    if wrap_flag_x or wrap_flag_y:
        xList.append(np.nan)
        yList.append(np.nan)
    xList.append(x)
    yList.append(y)    

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(xList,yList,c="b")
ax.set_xlim(-N/2,N/2)
ax.set_ylim(-N/2,N/2)
ax.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
ax.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
```

They are putting `np.nan` (Not A Number, which is part of the float 
spec) into your list.  When mpl is drawing lines it (with the default line style) connects all of the points.  The points that are `np.nan` can't be drawn to the screen so the line from the last point to the `np.nan` point is not drawn and the line from the `np.nan` to the next point is not drawn, hence the break in your line.
[image: output]

As a side note, most of this simulation can be vectorized:

```
from numpy.random import randint
from numpy import cos, sin, radians, cumsum
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 100   # Size of square as a multiple of the step size.
NSteps = 5000   # Number of steps in simulation.
x_start = 0   # x coordinate of starting location. Origin is at centre of square
y_start = 0   # y coordinate of starting location. Origin is at centre of square



# get all of the angles
angles = radians(randint(low=0, high=361, size=NSteps))

# get (unwrapped) positions
x = cumsum(cos(angles)) + x_start
y = cumsum(sin(angles)) + y_start

# find where the position crosses the boundary
x_wraps = np.where(np.diff((x + N/2) // N))[0]
y_wraps = np.where(np.diff((y + N/2) // N))[0]

# do the wrapping
x = x - N * ((x + N/2)//N)
y = y - N * ((y + N/2)//N)
```

I leave using the wrap locations to insert nans as an exercise for the reader ;)

Comment: Thank you for the nice answer, but unfortunately I don't understand how it works! What exactly are `xList.append(np.nan)` and `yList.append(np.nan)` doing?